# Excel - how to get a result if both "YES" from multiple rows with a same ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to write a formula to get the result in column D? if column B & C both have "YES" with same Column A's ID, show "YES", if NOT, show "NO" in column D (Both?).

[image: Sample Sheet]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. First try your own formula, and if you need help after attempting it, post what you tried and what happened. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you have Excel365, use `Filter` to get rows that match your criteria.  If any rows are returned then "yes", else "No"

Comment: `AND(COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, B:B, "YES")>0, COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, C:C, "YES")>0)`

Comment: @TimWilliams it looks great! but if I really want to show "YES" or "NO" instead of True or False? what can i do?

Comment: `IF(AND(COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, B:B, "YES")>0, COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, C:C, "YES")>0), "YES", "NO")`